# How to add values into routing table so that i can see those in netstat -p

Tags: netstat

when I use `netstat -pn` into my server I got following result:

```
Device   IP Address               Mask      Flags      Phys Addr
------ -------------------- --------------- -------- ---------------
asd0   10.213.213.121        255.255.255.255          00:00:00:00:01:04
dsa0   10.213.222.111        255.255.255.255 o        00:00:11:07:a0:19`
```

I want to add one IP address into `dsa0` device. What command i should use to add the value?

Comment: You would probably get an answer quicker on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: `route add ...` or `ip route add ...`